# Extract cell values and coordinates from raster using a polygon in R

Tags: raster, r, coordinates, remote-sensing, extract

I'm trying to extract cell values and coordinates from raster using a polygon in R. I have multiple raster layers with different types of values, all within the same extent. I have multiple polygons within these rasters data set areas.

I want to use the polygons to extract the raster cell values and coordinates within each cell.

I'm using this code for example:

```
library("raster")
library("rgdal")
library("shapefiles")
library("rgeos")
library("sp")

values_cps <- extract(CPs,cp_layer,cellnumbers=T)

cp_values <- as.data.frame(values_cps)

write.csv(cp_values,file="RCP95_cps.csv")
```

where: `CPs` is a raster layer, `cp_layer` is a polygon.

When I write the csv it gives me a column of cell ID numbers and a column of the values of each cell. I want to get the coordinates to come with it.

I've tried using `coordinates()` which I'm successfully using for the raster file, but not the extracted file.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

you can use the `raster::xyFromCell` function to get a matrix of coordinates from a vector of cell numbers, which you can cbind onto the extract (as the xyFromCell result is in exactly the same order as the vector provided)

I've used `sf` but of course this works with readOGR etc.;

```
require(raster)
require(sf)

# make 2 dummy rasters for a dummy stack
r <- raster(xmn=0,xmx=10,ymn=0,ymx=10,res=1)
r[] <- sample(1:4,100,replace=T)

r2 <- raster(xmn=0,xmx=10,ymn=0,ymx=10,res=1)
r2[] <- sample(8:10,100,replace=T)

s <- stack(r,r2)

# make a triangle simple feature
s2 <- rbind(c(2.2,2.2), c(3.3,8.5), c(5.3,0.8), c(2.2,2.2))
s2.sf <-st_sfc(st_polygon(list(s2)))
s2.pol = st_sf(ID = "tr", s2.sf)

# extract values into data frame
ex.df <- as.data.frame(extract(s,s2.pol,cellnumbers=T))

# create coordinate columns using xyFromCell
ex.df.coords <- cbind(ex.df, xyFromCell(s,ex.df[,1]))
```

Comment: Thanks @Sam.This code adopted from yours worked a treat!                  
'''values_cps <- as.data.frame(extract(CPs,cp_layer,cellnumbers=T))
cp_values_coords <- cbind(values_cps, xyFromCell(CPs,values_cps[,1]))
cp_values_coords
write.csv(cp_values_coords,file="RCP95_cps.csv")'''

Comment: no probelm @Cam, can you press the answered button if it's the correct one? glad it helped

Answer (score 2):

You can get a table of cell values, coverage fractions, and center coordinates with the `include_xy` argument to [`exactextractr::exact_extract`](https://isciences.gitlab.io/exactextractr/reference/exact_extract.html). Here's an example:

```
library(raster)
library(sf)
library(exactextractr)

# Pull municipal boundaries for Brazil
brazil <- st_as_sf(getData('GADM', country='BRA', level=2))[1:10, ]
    
# Pull gridded precipitation data
prec <- getData('worldclim', var='prec', res=10)[[12]]
    
prec_dfs <- exact_extract(prec, brazil, include_xy=TRUE, include_cols='GID_2')
```

This produces a list (`prec_dfs`) with one data frame for each feature in `brazil`. Each data frame looks like this:

```
       GID_2 value         x          y coverage_fraction
1  BRA.1.1_1   227 -67.08333  -9.750000        0.42837274
2  BRA.1.1_1   223 -66.91667  -9.750000        0.39436889
3  BRA.1.1_1   219 -66.75000  -9.750000        0.03865873
4  BRA.1.1_1   230 -67.08333  -9.916667        0.60549742
5  BRA.1.1_1   225 -66.91667  -9.916667        1.00000000
```

where `value` is the value of `prec` at the cell whose center coordinates are `x` and `y`, `coverage_fraction` of which is covered by the polygon.

These data frames can then be combined into a single table with `rbind`:

```
tbl <- do.call(rbind, prec_dfs)
```